# Definition of $x^a$

Tags: calculus, foundations

**How is $x^a$ for $x \in \mathbb{R},a>0$ defined?**

For $x>0$ I think one can define it as $e^{a ln(x)}$. For $x<0$ I am not sure anymore. I think that $x^\frac{3}{5}=(x^5)^\frac{1}{3}$ makes sense somehow but for $x^\frac{3}{2}$this doesn't work anymore. Maybe somebody knows how to define these power functions properly.

Comment: If we're working in real numbers, $x^a$ cannot be generally defined for $x<0$. As you mentioned, $x^{3/2}$ would make no sense. The exception is when $a$ is an integer in which case $x^a=x\cdot x\cdots x$ or when $a$ is a rational with odd denominator when written in lowest terms in which case $x^{p/q}=\sqrt[q]{x^p}$.

Comment: If $x\gt0$ you can equivalently define it as follows: if $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots)$ is the Cauchy sequence of rationals representing $a\in\Bbb R$ (and such a sequence always exists by construction of $\Bbb R$), then $x^a=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{a_n}$ where the powers $x^{a_n}$ are easily defined as the $a_n$ are rational. If $x$ is negative, you delve into complex numbers very quickly, and $x^a=\exp(a\cdot\operatorname{Log}x+a\cdot2\pi i k),\,k\in\Bbb Z$ is the used way to extend exponentiation (as a multivalued function!).

Comment: As an example of the sequence definition, $x^{\pi}$ can be considered as the limit of the sequence: $x^3,x^{3.1},x^{3.14},x^{3.1415926535},\cdots$